# Google Sheets - Stacked Query utilizing a semicolon - automatically changing back to a , WHY?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Here's a 16 second video of what is happening: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/19789901?key=e27c9f8e0c693b53469f1491b52d2cf6

I just had a stacked query on this sheet. I had to pull from a different data source so I needed to change it but when I press enter it changes the data back to a , instead of leaving it as a ;. Is there anything I can do to fix it tonight or is this just a google bug.

I tried to manually type out the formula, I tried to copy and paste the formula, I tried to delete the line and add it to a new cell, and I deleted the whole sheet and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=vstack([YOUR_QUERY_1],[YOUR_QUERY_2],[YOUR_QUERY_3])
```

- skip `arrayformula` usage in this scenario (as in the vid)

Comment: You are a genius. (I think you helped me last time.). I have never used vstack. I love it!